# (How) Can you combine moving average and exponential smoothing filters to get smoother trends?

Tags: time-series, smoothing, moving-average, exponential-smoothing

**Goal:** Have a *machine* perform smoothing on time series data set to have a smooth *looking* trend. The *correctness* of the trend is balanced by being *optimal* i.e., minimize the MSE (Mean Standard Error).

**Problem**: The data is rather *variable* i.e., variance/standard-deviation is rather high. A single pass through a Single Exponential Smoothing (SES) filter is rather *jagged*. The Moving Average (MA) filter smooths better with higher window size but drops a lot of data values from the output trend by definition. Can we balance this somehow using *both* filters?

Here's what I think (`a->b` means first `a` then `b`):

1. `MA -> MA`: This seems doable and recommended with even-sized windows. So you can do a `4MA -> 2MA`. No questions here.
2. `SES -> MA`: This also seems reasonable. We can calculate an $\alpha$-value for which the MSE is minimized and then if we wish to smoothen it further we can pass it through an `n-MA` filter for some window-size $n$. I don't think there is a cause for concern here either and it may still be *optimally smooth* owing to the prior SES filter (right?).
3. `MA -> SES`: This one has me confused. The optimization step of SES of solving for $\alpha$ will invariably lead to $\alpha = 1$. The perfect fit with the prior output of MA technically *minimizes* the SES! How can a *program* decide what value of $\alpha$ to use? Hence, I wonder if this is even recommended/practiced and if so, what's the *rule* (or guideline) for selecting the value of $\alpha$? The closest I found was in the trading world was to set $\alpha = \frac{2}{1+n}$ where $n = $ window size of MA. But how is that *optimal* in any sense? It looks more like a heuristic and I couldn't find any mathematical backing to the idea. What am I missing?
4. `SES -> SES`: I'm genuinely curious about this. Similar to `#3` the second SES filter would set $\alpha = 1$ for the same reason. But this time, I don't even know what heuristic/rule to use for selecting $\alpha$. Is this even done in practice? I couldn't find any examples anywhere.

As I said before, the goal is to get a smooth *looking* function and I'm looking to *codify* that rule to have the machine/program do it and was wondering specifically for MA and SES if we can combine them and does it happen *in the wild* or should we avoid doing this? I am minimizing the MSE and perhaps that is the cause of the confusion but is there another alternative or do we avoid mixing MA and SES filters for exactly these reasons?